# Read excel sheet starting from specific col

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets and I am trying to import/read the data starting from any empty col before col C.

the row data look like this

| A |  | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |

and I am trying to get the data

|  | C |
| --- | --- |
| Two | Three |

I can't use usecols as the position of this empty col changes in each sheet I have in the workbook. So it will optimal to start always from whatever empty col located before col C

I have tried this but didn't work out for me.

```
df = df[df.columns[list(df.columns)[-1]]
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or hints. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need solution for return all values if not exist empty string use:

```
m1 = df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')
m2 = (df.columns == 'C').cumsum() == 0

m = m1 & m2

print (df.iloc[:, m[::-1].argmax():])
```

EDIT:

Pandas solution for get column before `C`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[8, 1,2],
                   'A':[8, 1,2],
                   'C':[1,2,0],
                   'D':[1,2,0]})


df = df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc('C')-1:]
print (df)
   A  C  D
0  8  1  1
1  1  2  2
2  2  0  0
```

---

If column `C` is first, need `max` for select all columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C':[8, 1,2],
                   'D':[1,2,0]})
    
df = df.iloc[:, max(0, df.columns.get_loc('C')-1):]
print (df)
   C  D
0  8  1
1  1  2
2  2  0
```

Solution working well in first DataFrame:

```
df = df.iloc[:, max(0, df.columns.get_loc('C')-1):]
print (df)
   A  C  D
0  8  1  1
1  1  2  2
2  2  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The issue is in the df I have, there are multiple empty cols and I am only interested in the empty col before C. Is there a way to read starting from any empty col falls before col C

Comment: @Kimchi - Can you test now?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be able to read the empty cols when running m1

Comment: @Kimchi - What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` for dataframe which failed solution?

Comment: it is the same as the original df:['A', 'Unnamed: 0','C']

Comment: @Kimchi - can you check now? Is necessary test `Unnamed` ?

Comment: I have actually ended up doing the following:
df = df[df[list(df.columns).index('C') - 1:]] 

Thanks again!

Comment: @Kimchi - Answer was EDITed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column name is an empty string(`''`), try slicing:

```
df.loc[:, '':]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for garagnoth to help with this issue, I have ended up doing the following:

`df = df[df[list(df.columns).index('C') - 1:]]`